# lucene custom scoring

Tags: java, lucene

Having a document already indexed, at search i must part that document in two: first part consist of the first 100 words (tokens) and the rest of the document represents the second part. I have to score this two parts like this: **the second part with 70%** and the **first with 30%**.

**EDIT 2:** So i tried creating a Searcher that uses SpanPositionRangeQuery, but i must have understood SpanQuery usage all wrong because i can't get any hits (i used lukeall to verify if the words i was searching were indexed). Can someone give me a hand?

```
public static void search(String indexDir, String q) throws Exception
{

    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir), null);
    IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(dir);

    Term term = new Term("Field", q);
    SpanPositionRangeQuery spanQuery = new SpanPositionRangeQuery(new SpanTermQuery(term), 0, 100);
    spanQuery.setBoost(0.3f);CustomRomanianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35));

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    TopDocs hits = is.search(spanQuery, 10);
    //TopDocs hits = is.search(query, 10);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.err.println("I found " + hits.totalHits + " documents (in " +
            (end - start) + " milliseconds) '" +
            q + "':");

    for (int i=0;i<hits.scoreDocs.length;i++)
    {
        ScoreDoc scoreDoc = hits.scoreDocs[i];
        Document doc = is.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
        System.out.println(doc.get("filename"));
    }

    is.close();
}
```

I don't know how to combine query parser with SpanPositionRangeQuery to get what i need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by setting the boost for each clause in a BooleanQuery.  Using separate fields will work, but isn't strictly necessary.  Lucene has a [SpanPositionRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanPositionRangeQuery.html) suitable for searching part of a document.

```
<SpanPositionRangeQuery: spanPosRange(field:term, 0, 100)^0.3>
```

Comment: I tried to do it so, but i have no idea how to link the query with the parser. I edited my question with the code i tried.